# Dynamically assigning json response content-type in WCF Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, wcf-rest, azureservicebus

I am writing a POC application which uses Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll 1.0.0.0 (the .NET 3.5 version).

My WCF contract  and service look like the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="MyServiceContract", Namespace = "http://mydomain.com/")]
internal interface IServiceContract
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/DoOperation")]
    [OperationContract]
    Stream RelayRequest(Stream requestBody);
}

[ServiceBehavior(Name = "Service1", Namespace = "http://mydomain.com/Service1/", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
internal class Service1 : IServiceContract
{
    Stream RelayRequest(Stream requestBody)
    {
        var contents = GetJsonResponse();
        var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(responseStream);
        streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(responseStream, contents);

        responseStream.Position = 0 // reset the position of the stream so that it's contents will be read from the beginning.

        //Problem Line:
        WebOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
        return responseStream;
    }
}
```

The listening end point is configured to use WebHttpRelayBinding:

- SecurityMode: Transport
- TransferMode: Streamed

When I attempt to assign the ContentType of the outgoing response to "application/json" an error doesn't occur but the calling request returns with status code 504 (Gateway Timeout).

If I change the ContentType to "text/javascript" the calling request returns with 200 (OK).

Some things to note:

- The content-type is not known until run time so it must be dynamically assigned.
- The contents of the stream is pure - 100% valid - json.
- The intention for accepting and returning a stream is so we can accept streamed requests and stream data down to the client.

  - Each request / response could contain a small json payload or a 200MB document.
- If you want to repro - this code uses the Newtonsoft Json library for serialization.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

**EDIT: The 504 status code could be a red herring inferred by fiddler** with which I am testing.
Sending the same request from System.Net.Http.HttpClient indicates the connection is closed before a response is received.

**EDIT: setting the content-type to pretty much anything else (including non-sensical values) works fine.** The only content type that I can get to break it is application/json

Comment: Can you add the info from your config file / how you set up the service? What type of binding are you using?

Comment: As pointed out above we use WebHttpRelayBinding. This binding / end point is not created by config, it is created programatically at runtime.

Comment: Ah, guess I had a series of mental lapses reading your description...

Comment: Any progress on solving this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. We ended up working around this with custom headers.

Comment: [sound of a crow] me.  this is absurd.  i think i might see what Godot suggests I do.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I made it work but it's a simple WCF service hosted locally in IIS. I don't use Microsoft.ServiceBus or Azure.

First Fiddler's response. If this is what you are looking for then proceed to code :)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 121
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2013 17:17:05 GMT

[{"BoolValue":true,"StringValue":"blah"},{"BoolValue":false,"StringValue":"boo"},{"BoolValue":true,"StringValue":"floo"}]
```

Service definition:

```
namespace yourNS
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/CT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<CompositeType> GetData();
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public List<CompositeType> GetData()
        {
            return new List<CompositeType>
            {
                new CompositeType { BoolValue = true, StringValue = "blah" },
                new CompositeType { BoolValue = false, StringValue = "boo" },
                new CompositeType { BoolValue = true, StringValue = "floo" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="yourNS.Service1">
        <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="MyBehave"
          contract="yourNS.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehave">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your solution only works because you've removed all of the complexity from the original question that was causing the problem in the first place. As stated in the original question I need to dynamically assign the response content type, I also need to use Azure Service Bus to achieve this.